# state at compile time not known

Tags: c#

I need a way to Parse an string into an integer value in c#. The problem is the user chosses a string from a combo box which contains strings such as "AAAAA" or "5". That means only at run time it is known if the parameter is a real string or an string which can be parsed to an integer. I tried around with reflection and have the fitting Parameter object.

```
ParameterInfo p = ps[i];
Type t = p.ParameterType;
```

I don't know how to go on from there or if it even is possible. I can't use if else statments because the program is supposed to load other interfaces with new parameters as well. So I could handle the default ones with if else statmentes but when a new interface with new Methodinfos is loaded that dos not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not usre that understood all your constraints. However you can parse string by using Int32.TryParse in case target string is not necessarily valid.

Answer (score 1):

Int32.TryParse whould help you with that

Answer (score 0):

To parse a string into an integer, you can use `Convert.ToInt32(string_var)`, or any of the other conversion methods. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx) for more.